# jQuery UI datepicker classes Option not overwriting default classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

As per the [classes option guide here](https://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/widget-factory/classes-option/), I tried to overwrite the default classes used by jQuery ui datepicker.

The datepicker doesn't have a `.prototype`, like the other widgets, so `$.ui.datepicker.prototype` is `undefined`.

I've tried to specify `classes` option for each `.datepicker` instance like so:

```
$('.datepicker_selector').datepicker({ 
    classes: { "ui-datepicker": "custom_class_name" },
...
```

but with no success.

I've opened a ticket at the jQuery ui git repo, I'm wondering if anyone has solved this? (The datepicker works fine, no errors in console either).

Thank you for your feedback!

Comment: Possible solution is to use `beforeShow`, I'm aware of that

Comment: A possible start: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/ofkude4b/1/

Comment: Thanks Twisty, I gave up and used beforeShow - as it seems, no other option is available for the datepicker.

Comment: Yes this is the case due to it's more dynamic nature.

Comment: unfortunately, `beforeShow` is not called when using the datepicker inline (on a div, not on an input)

Comment: For inline datepickers you can use `beforeShowDay` callback with some delay by using `clearTimeout` and `setTimeout` properly.